# Jquery ambiguous ajax error

Tags: ajax, jquery

This is the gut of my ajax call.

```
function ajax(path, requestData, successCallBack, errorCallBack) {
    return $.ajax({
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            ç(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
        },
        success: function(json){ 
            successCallBack(json);
        }
    });
}
```

When there is an ajax call going on and the user clicks on a link on the page, my errorCallBack is invoked. The user navigating away would cause the ajax call to be killed.
When there is an error on the server, my errorCallBack callback is also invoked.

Is there a way to differentiate the two?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

@colbeerhey's answer is good, but you can go one step further.  You still need to know if the server actually is unreachable.  I asked that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977870/in-a-ajax-callback-how-do-i-distinguish-an-unreachable-server-from-a-user-navi), but the full answer is:

```
var running = true;
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() { running = false; });

$.ajax({
    /* ajax options omitted */
    error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         var serverNotReached = xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 0 || xmlHttpRequest.status == 0;
         if(serverNotReached && !running) 
              return;  // it's not really an error, user clicked away
         else if (serverNotReached)
              // The server is down!  You didn't get any response at all.
         else
              // Do normal error handling
});
```

Keep in mind that onbeforeunload is only really a de facto standard (IE FF, Webkit all handle it) so this will break if you care about more obscure browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with something I was working on... A 'canceled' $.ajax request (user navigates away / hits stop) xhr.status == 0 instead of 200/404/etc...

Comment: This wouldn't differentiate between a user navigating away and a completely unreachable server, though.  I don't think it works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's is the technique I used to implement gnarf's and nickf's answers:

jQuery throws the error event when the user navigates away from the page either by refreshing, clicking a link, or changing the URL in the browser.  You can detect these types of errors by by implementing an error handler for the ajax call, and inspecting the xmlHttpRequest object:

```
$.ajax({
    /* ajax options omitted */
    error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 0 || xmlHttpRequest.status == 0) 
              return;  // it's not really an error
         else
              // Do normal error handling
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the xhr object's properties. It should have the HTTP response code in it somewhere.