# In a $.ajax callback, how do I distinguish an unreachable server from a user navigating away?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Situation:

You've got a few $.ajax requests to the server that are still running.  They all error out with xhr.status === 0 and xhr.readyState === 0.

Possible causes:

- The server is down (EDIT: as in unreachable - no headers are returned or anything).
- The user clicked a link/refreshed the page/otherwise navigated away.

I would like to pop up a dialog in the first case, but ignore the second.  How do I distinguish between these two in my complete method?  The complete method is fired before the $(window).unload event, so I can't use that to determine if the user clicked away.  I could also use a setTimeout to try to wait for the next page to load, but that's dirty.  Is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer is an abstract of another answer, for clarity's sake by the OP's request)
If a window level flag isn't working, the next dom level event to test before `$(window).unload` is `window.onbeforeunload`. Is that a viable option?

Around your AJAX method:

```
var running = true;
// do this only once!!!
var _obunload = ( window.onbeforeunload )? window.onbeforeunload: function(){};
window.onbeforeunload = function() 
{ 
     _obunload.call( window );
     running = false;
}
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if( !xhr.status && !xhr.readyState && running )
    {
        // warning! warning! danger Will Robinson!
        // there was a server error
    }
    else if( !xhr.status && !xhr.readyState )
    {
        // user did something... Who gives?
    }
    running = false;
}
```

Comment: I don't have edit privileges yet, but for anyone trying to use this:  THe code itself doesn't actually work, but the idea is correct - use a boolean indicator of "Whether the user clicked away" that defaults to true, but is set to false in onbeforeunload.  Use that boolean to tell the difference between "AJAX failed because there is no response from the server" (boolean is true) and "AJAX was cancelled when the user navigated away from the page" (boolean is false).

Answer (score 0):

You can check for a timeout response from the server:

```
timeout:500,
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if(textStatus==="timeout") {
        alert("got timeout");
    } else {
        // Some other error
    }
}
```

Comment: No you receive nothing at all - the server is unreachable.

Comment: so xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() returns an empty string either way.  Same is true for jqXhr.getAllResponseHeaders()

Comment: textStatus is "error" in both cases.  There's no "timeout" that would apply here...

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying.  But you're really changing the problem there - I don't need a timeout because the AJAX returns quickly in either case.  Using a timeout would check for server-slow, not server-down.

Comment: "server-slow" and "server-down" are the same for the user bro. That's what timeouts are for. Plus if you're receiving an error at all, that's a good thing because it obviously wasn't triggered by the user clicking on a link.

Comment: Sure, they are the same to the user, but they are not the same to the developer. By handling a slow server I'm not also handling a downed server.  You gave me an answer to the wrong problem.  Also, a user clicking a link definitely DOES give an error (that's how jQuery reports it).  No offense, but maybe you should slow down with your answers - you threw an answer together without actually understanding the problem and now both of us have wasted time.

Answer (score 0):

### Idea 3

Well, there is always the possibility of faking a delay from the non-existent server:

```
var running = true;
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if( !xhr.status && !xhr.readyState )
    {
        // wait a short while to see whether the page is unloading.
        setTimeout( unloadTest, 250 );
    }
    else
    {
        running = false;
    }
}

function unloadTest()
{
    // running will be set to false by onbeforeunload, which means this
    // should only be true if there was some form of server error.
    if( running ) // Regnad? Robin Williams?
}
```

Then, elsewhere:

```
// (using generic JS, you can use $(window).bind( 'beforeunload' ...
window.onbeforeunload = function() 
{ 
     running = false;
}
```

### Idea 2

Well, if below isn't working, the next dom level event to test before `$(window).unload` is `window.onbeforeunload`. Is that a viable option?

Around your AJAX method:

```
var running = true;
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if( !xhr.status && !xhr.readyState && running )
    {
        // warning! warning! danger Will Robinson!
        // there was a server error
    }
    else if( !xhr.status && !xhr.readyState )
    {
        // user did something... Who gives?
    }
    running = false;
}
```

Then, elsewhere:

```
// (using generic JS, you can use $(window).bind( 'beforeunload' ...
window.onbeforeunload = function() 
{ 
     running = false;
}
```

### Original post (apparently is not working)

Why not set a flag on the window itself?

```
<html>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        // window.currentTime will update *first* after every page refresh.
        window.currentTime = new Date().getTime()
   </script>
   <!-- continue as normal -->
```

Then, when you're about to call `$.ajax`:

```
// winTime is bound to window.currentTime at the time of the original query.
var winTime = window.currentTime;
// using onreadystatechange because it looks like you're looking for that in your
// question. This can be easily adapted to $.ajax, however.
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if( !xhr.status && !xhr.readyState && winTime == window.currentTime )
    {
        // warning! warning! danger Will Robinson!
        // there was a server error
    }
    else if( !xhr.status && !xhr.readyState )
    {
        // user did something... Who gives?
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Solves the problem. Perhaps instead of attaching it to the window it could be put in a scope where the ajax call is made? That way multiple ajax calls could be made and watched in the same manner without conflicting.

Comment: This actually doesn't solve the problem.  The new page doesn't really come into the equation anyway, so winTime === window.currentTime will still be true in both cases.  The page still hasn't unloaded (yet) at this point.

Comment: @tjameson You'd basically need some outside constant which could track multiple calls simultaneously. I'd like a utility class for that.

Comment: @Adam I just suggested `window.onbeforeunload`. Does that work? (yes, I know, it is proprietary, but MS, Chrome, and FF all seem to support it)

Comment: Yeah I would have loved that to work, but it's still too late in the cycle (at least for Chrome).  What happens is the AJAX requests are killed as soon as the user clicks, but the unload event doesn't fire until the next page is done loading (and starts rendering).  I'm going to double check onbeforeunload again just to be sure it doesn't work.  Had some weirdness with it last time I tried.

Comment: @Adam A- Something like this should work. A DNS fail will take up to 120 seconds on Chrome, so if the timeout is >= the difference in the request and response, then we know it timed out. If it is near the same time, the DNS succeeded but the server gave back an error. Navigation away, however, should be somewhere in the middle. This is a relatively small fringe case, so perhaps only the timeout is interesting.

Comment: @Adam OK, suggestion 3, fake an additional lag in the case of an error, let onbeforeunload set a flag to cancel the error, if that cancel command is never received, show message.

Comment: The lag was my backup.  Was really hoping I wouldn't have to do that.
Tried onbeforeunload again, and it worked.  BUT I had to do it directly on window (as in window.onbeforeunload = function... instead of $(window).bind('beforeunload', function....).  Weird!  Going to check this is good cross-browser

Comment: Ok, so somebody decided to write code to set window.onbeforeunload without calling whatever function was already there.  So jQuery's unbeforeunload handling was getting ruined.  Idea 2 is perfect - Can you pare this answer down to that or create a new answer with just that?  I'll accept it.